# Erro ao recolher valor da va_list em C

Tags: mysql, c, sqlite3

Boa tarde.
me deparei com um problema na hora de prepara a `va_list` em c. de dois códigos semelhantes, um funciona e outro persiste em erro.

```
extern bool _sqlite3_insert(const char *table, const char *types, ...){
    M_HEADER; // macro com as variáveis data, argv e swap
    // data é char [2][500], swap é char [500] e argv é uma va_list

    va_start(argv,types);
    clear(data[0]);
    clear(data[1]);

    while(types && *types){
        swap = va_arg(argv, char *);

        if(find_quots(swap))
            return false;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

até ai tudo bem... o erro começa nesse método.

```
extern bool _mysql_insert(const char *table, const char *types, ...){
    M_HEADER; // macro com as variáveis data, argv e swap
    // data é char [2][500], swap é char [500] e argv é uma va_list

    va_start(argv,types);
    clear(data[0]);
    clear(data[1]);

    while(types && *types){
        swap = va_arg(argv, char *);

        if(find_quots(swap))
            return false;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Como podem ver, ambos os métodos são idênticos, com diferença apenas no nome, o método _sqlite3_insert, funciona normal, mas no método _mysql_insert, ocorre o erro em `swap = va_arg(argv, char *)`

O erro do compilador é o seguinte:

```
src/mysql_conn.c:20:23: error: expected expression before ‘char’
swap = va_arg(argv, char*);
```

Alguém saberia dizer o porque e como posso resolver esse problema?
Obg.

Comment: Seria molhar que mostrasses as partes **diferentes** do codigo. Mostrar as partes iguais torna dificil encontrar as **diferencas**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica se na versao com `_mysql_insert()` tens o `#include <stdarg.h>`.

Comment: erá bem isso mesmo, agora funcionou perfeitamente. vlw